# Синонимизировать [макросы]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать [макросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b), [макрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81) и [macro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro) в пользу [макросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b).

Comment: Там в кучу и макросы препроцессора C++, и макросы как средство автоматизации работы с UI. Надо бы определиться сначала, что эта метка значит, и нужна ли она вообще.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если глянуть на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros), то для vba просят не использовать эту метку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что ж, только ради этого стоило избираться в модераторы.

Синонимизировал :)

Comment: А насчет проблемы из моего комментария таки что делать? Она за 4 года не исчезла. Макросы процессора С++ - это не совсем то же, что макросы как "алгоритм записанных действий в UI". Для первых стоит искать другую метку, например [define]?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight на enSO есть метка [c-preprocessor]. У нас тоже есть похожая [tag:препроцессор], но не специфичная для сишечки.