# Слишком много меток "макрос"

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Я видел, что этот вопрос [уже поднимали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8695/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B) в 2021 году, но почему-то (совершенно неясно почему) эти метки так и не поудаляли. Предлагаю пересмотреть проблему синонимизации/удаления меток [macro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro), [макросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b) и [макрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81).